# How should I take the concept of the following sentence?

Tags: philosophy

In this following context, how should I take the bold and italic sentence?

Should I take it as: 'it is no longer known more important than all.'?

Should I take its concept meaning as: 'the matter is known nothing rather than all changing.'?

Context:

> Till recently scientists believed in an indivisible and indestructible
> atom. “For sufficient reasons physicists have reduced this atom to a
> series of events. For equally good reasons psychologists find that
> mind has not the identity of a single continuing thing but is a series
> of occurrences bound together by certain intimate relations. The
> question of immortality, therefore, has become the question whether
> these intimate relations exist between occurrences connected with a
> living body and other occurrences which take place after that body is
> dead.”
>
> As C. E. M. Joad says in The Meaning of Life, “matter has since
> disintegrated under our very eyes. It is no longer solid; it is no
> longer enduring; it is no longer determined by compulsive causal laws;
> ***and more important than all, it is no longer known.*** The so-called atoms, it seems, are both ‘divisible and destructible.” The
> electrons and protons that compose atoms ‘can meet and annihilate one
> another while their persistence, such as it is, is rather that of a
> wave lacking fixed boundaries, and in process of continual change both
> as regards shape and position than that of a thing.”

Source: P. 59
Buddhism in a Nutshell
by Narada Thera

Comment: You need to give more context.

Comment: Thanks @Dheeraj Verma. I put more context there. I hope your explanation to this.

Answer (score 0):

“It is no longer known” means that science now says that everything is now quantum mechanical. It is no longer known how to interpret quantum mechanics…